# Error: Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address

Tags: node.js, twilio

Im using twilio for whatsapp API, but the problem right now is that i keep getting this error

> Error: Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address

Here's the code

```
const express = require('express')
const accountSid = '-'
const authToken = '-'
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken)
const request = require('request')

const app = express()


app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    client.messages
      .create({
        body: 'Hello there!',
        from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
        to: 'whatsapp:+myNumber'
      })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
      .done()

      res.json('Done')
})

app.listen(3030, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to the port 3030')
    }
})
```

Sandbox picture

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Have you sent the whatsapp number the message to join the sandbox for your account? It's normally a message that starts "connect" and then has two random words.

Comment: I get the same error.  Perhaps you need to add a WhatApp Channel https://www.twilio.com/console/channels but WhatsApp is not listed there (but Faceook, e.g., is).

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved @airsoftFreak? I've just started playing with the Twilio API and am getting the same result

Comment: Has anyone solved this issue? I am stuck with this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8):

This error occurs due to 1 of 3 reasons.

- The `From` address in your Messaging API request is incorrect. To send messages using WhatsApp, the `From` address should be `whatsapp:<sandbox phone number>`. This can be found on the sandbox page in Twilio.
- You are trying to send a message from an account that does not have an activated sandbox.
- You are using your test Account SID and TOKEN. For whatever reason, Twilio needs your Production Account SID and TOKEN when using the WhatsApp sandbox for testing.

Comment: Using test credentials caused this to me. The should reflect this detail in docs.

Comment: Can anyone point me to where the 'production account' tokens are I only see the ones on my dashboard. Are those they?

Comment: Go to the settings tab. You'll find your test and live credentials there.

Comment: This answer is just a copy and paste from Twilio QA, it does not solve this specific issue.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it still relevant but I'm currently testing out the Twilio whatsapp API in their sandbox (with a trail account) and I haven't added/bought any phone numbers so far.

What i noticed is that when you send a test messages from their console page and you look closely to the curl request (what is send to the API) on the console page they are always using the production clientid token combination.

While i was implementing the Client i assumed that i should use the test clientid token combination (because of common sense :)) but after inspecting the curl request i switched to the production clientid and token and I was able to send test messages to my own sandbox. (Using the sandbox 'from' phonenumber provided on the same page and only to my own private phonenumber which has been added to the sandbox)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You're right, it's correct. If you're facing the same issue, you can get both tokens in this page: (https://www.twilio.com/console)

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned you need to use your production account SID and token. If you use the test account sid and token, you will see this error. There is another reason why you see this error - if you swap From mobile number with To mobile number, then also you will see the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar error, when i modified from number to number of twilio sandbox to which we need to activate to receive whatsapp message, issue got resolved.

Steps i followed to resolve this issue:

1.Need to create channel ie, activating twilio sandbox to receive whatsapp message like shown in this url : https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/sandbox

2.Need to specify from number( from: 'whatsapp:(number specified in above url)') .

Comment: i had the same issue. After various trying, this response help me. 
I was using the number show in the Dashboard but this isn't correct.