# com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address

Tags: java, twilio

I have been trying to send a message to a whatsApp using Twilio but the code on their website is not working for me throwing exception

> Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address
>       at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:471)
>       at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:25)
>       at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
>       at com.lt.WhatsAppTest.main(WhatsAppTest.java:16)

**This is my code**

```
package com.lt;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;

public class WhatsAppTest
{
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "my_token";
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "my_acc_SID";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
       Message message = Message.creator(
               new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:to"),
               new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:from"),
               "Hello from your friendly neighborhood Java application!")
           .create();

       System.out.print(message.getDateSent().toString());
   }
}
```

I have used the phone number including `country code`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941133/error-twilio-could-not-find-a-channel-with-the-specified-from-address)